# Inserting List of strings as list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add items to a Appointment item.

Appointment is a class as follows:

```
Appointment Appointment({   
String? startTimeZone,   
String? endTimeZone,   
String? recurrenceRule,   
bool isAllDay = false,   
String? notes,   
String? location,   
List<Object>? resourceIds,   
Object? recurrenceId,   
Object? id,   
required DateTime startTime,   
required DateTime endTime,   
String subject = '',   
Color color = Colors.lightBlue,   
List<DateTime>? recurrenceExceptionDates, })
```

I am inserting Appointment items as follows:

```
List<Appointment> appointments = <Appointment>[];
    appointments.add(Appointment(
      startTime: DateTime.now(),
      endTime: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 1)),
      subject: 'Formación presencial',
      color: Colors.green,
      notes: "Formación presencial",
      location: "Zaragoza",
      resourceIds:  EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr"),

    ),);
```

But I don´t understand the concept of List of objects, I would like to add as resourcesIds an object from type EventObjects.

```
class EventObjects{
String? profId;
String? profColor;
String? profNombre;
String? profAvatar;
String? eventoTipo;
String? eventoColor;

// added '?'

  EventObjects({this.profId, this.profColor, this.profAvatar, this.profNombre, this.eventoColor, this.eventoTipo});
// can also add 'required' keyword
}
```

But I guess this is not the way to do it as the line

```
resourceIds:  EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr"),
```

is marked as error

```
The argument type 'EventObjects' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign here

```dart
resourceIds:  EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr"),
```

a `EventObjects` instance to a field `List<Object>?`

What you may want to do is to either declare the `resourceIds` as `Object` or `EventObjects` or make a list literal of `resourceIds` like this

```dart
resourceIds:  [EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr")],
```

Both will work

Comment: fine, it works and how can I then retrieve the values from appointmentDetails.resourceIds ?

Comment: You can find at the index by `appointmentDetails.resourceIds[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the mistake:

```js
Appointment Appointment({   
String? startTimeZone,   
String? endTimeZone,   
String? recurrenceRule,   
bool isAllDay = false,   
String? notes,   
String? location,   
List<Object>? resourceIds,  //here we're assigning as List<Object> which is 
                             // incorrect 
Object? recurrenceId,   
Object? id,   
required DateTime startTime,   
required DateTime endTime,   
String subject = '',   
Color color = Colors.lightBlue,   
List<DateTime>? recurrenceExceptionDates, })
```

You can do it this way:

```js
Appointment Appointment({   
String? startTimeZone,   
String? endTimeZone,   
String? recurrenceRule,   
bool isAllDay = false,   
String? notes,   
String? location,   
List<EventObjects>? resourceIds, 
Object? recurrenceId,   
Object? id,   
required DateTime startTime,   
required DateTime endTime,   
String subject = '',   
Color color = Colors.lightBlue,   
List<DateTime>? recurrenceExceptionDates, })
```

And you can assign like this:

```
resourceIds:[EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr")],
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are inserting a **Object** not `List<Object>` and your datatype for ***resourceIds*** is of `List<Object>?`.

You can try using this:

```
List<EventObjects>? eventsObjectList;
EventObjects eventObject = EventObjects(profId: "1",profAvatar: "as",profColor: "dd",profNombre: "ee",eventoColor: "Cc",eventoTipo: "Rr"); //Instance of EventObjects
List<Appointment> appointments = <Appointment>[];
eventsObjectList.add(eventObject);
appointments.add(Appointment(
  startTime: DateTime.now(),
  endTime: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 1)),
  subject: 'Formación presencial',
  color: Colors.green,
  notes: "Formación presencial",
  location: "Zaragoza",
  resourceIds: eventsObjectList),);
```